# ¿Cómo generar un script de introducción de datos en Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Esta duda me viene al pasar de Mysql a Oracle. En MySQL existe la opción de aplicar la siguiente sintaxis:

```
LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL] INFILE 'file_name'
[REPLACE | IGNORE]
INTO TABLE tbl_name
[PARTITION (partition_name [, partition_name] ...)]
[CHARACTER SET charset_name]
[{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
    [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
    [ESCAPED BY 'char']
]
[LINES
    [STARTING BY 'string']
    [TERMINATED BY 'string']
]
[IGNORE number {LINES | ROWS}]
[(col_name_or_user_var
    [, col_name_or_user_var] ...)]
[SET col_name={expr | DEFAULT},
    [, col_name={expr | DEFAULT}] ...]
```

Sin embargo en Oracle no veo la forma de hacerlo desde el script y todo lo que veo parece orientado a usar las propias herramientas de SQL Developer o SQL Loader.

Por un lado las herramientas de SQL Developer están muy bien pero por motivos lectivos no puedo andar haciendo la inserción de datos tabla por tabla cada vez que la cargo y quiero reiniciar la base de datos (7 tablas con más de 100 registros cada una).

Mientras que usar SQL Loader parece implicar hacer una llamada a un programa externo, una preparación de archivos para fallos, logs, etc... y lo único que quiero es ejecutar un simple script como hacía en MySQL.

Otra cosa que he intentado probar es, mediante la herramienta de importación de SQL Developer, generar scripts tabla por tabla y llamarlos desde otro script. Pero tampoco consigo saber el modo de hacerlo de forma correcta (o no he adquirido los conocimientos necesarios aun, por eso os pregunto).

¿Alguna pista de cómo podría hacerse?

Comment: ¡Hola Alo, bienvenido al Stack Overflow en español! Pásate por el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general (y ganar una medalla). Y si conseguiste resolver el problema por tu cuenta, por favor, ponlo como respuesta a la pregunta. Un saludo y suerte.

Comment: ¿te sirvió la respuesta de Roberto?

Answer (score 3):

Lo más cercano que tienes en Oracle a LOAD DATA de MySQL son las tablas externas, ficheros que no son parte de la base de datos pero que se pueden acceder como si fueran una tabla.

Para comodidad, lo mejor es que el formato de dicho archivo externo sea CSV.

A modo de ejemplo usemos uno (llamado datos.csv) así:

```
    1,Juan,Perez
    2,Fulanito,Quien
```

Una vez que tienes el archivo, lo primero es crear el objeto DIRECTORY que hará de interfaz con el path de nuestro archivo de datos:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY data_dir AS '/data/oracle/';
```

Lo siguiente, es darle a nuestro usuario permisos del lectura y escritura sobre dicho objeto:

```
    GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY data_dir TO roberto;
    GRANT WRITE ON DIRECTORY data_dir TO roberto;
```

Una vez que está hecha "la conexión" entre nuestra bbdd y el path es necesario que le indiquemos qué tiene la tabla:

```
    CREATE TABLE personas (
        id NUMBER(4),
        nombre VARCHAR(20),
        apellido VARCHAR(30)
    )
    ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
        TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
        DEFAULT DIRECTORY data_dir
        ACCESS PARAMETERS (
            RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
            NOBADFILE
            NOLOGFILE
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
            MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
            (
                id, nombre, apellido
            )
        )
        LOCATION ('datos.csv')
    )
    PARALLEL
    REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

A partir de este momento podrás trabajar con la tabla personas (casi) como cualquier otra.

Este ejemplo es meramente orientativo pero tiene todo lo que hace falta para hacerlo. Antes de implementarlo te conviene ver la sección correspondiente en el manual de Oracle:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-external-tables.html#GUID-038ED956-A6EE-4C6D-B7C9-0D406B8088B6